# Checking faster IP router address from JAVA, Android

Tags: java, android, sdk

I'm trying to check the connection of a specific IP address, so the problem is that, when I want to open this address (my IP router address), and if I'm not connected to this IP, I have to wait a lot of time, to tell me that I have no connection.

I tried this, and a lot of different java codes, but without success:

```
public String checkConnection() throws IOException {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        int timeout = 2000;
        InetAddress[] addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName("www.fritz.box");
        for (InetAddress address : addresses) {
            if (!address.isReachable(timeout)) {
                return "YES";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException exc) {
        return "NO";
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address resolution is done in `InetAddress.getAllByName("www.fritz.box")` and it has an implied timeout of 1 minute (if i remember correctly). A solution would be to run this request in another thread and ask for result.

Consider implementing a class as folows:

```
public class DNSResolver implements Runnable {
    private String domain;
    private InetAddress inetAddr;

    public DNSResolver(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(domain);
            // when IP address is found, make it accessible
            set(addr);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // IP address has not been found, ignore
        }
    }

    public synchronized void set(InetAddress inetAddr) {
        this.inetAddr = inetAddr;
    }
    public synchronized InetAddress get() {
        return inetAddr;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
DNSResolver dnsRes = new DNSResolver(host);
Thread t = new Thread(dnsRes);
// start resolving address in another thread
t.start();
// wait for a second for result
t.join(1000);
InetAddress inetAddr = dnsRes.get();
```

Code has been taken from http://thushw.blogspot.com/2009/11/resolving-domain-names-quickly-with.html.